# Window Function with a condition

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I have the below table.

Can I create a Window Function `First_Value` when a condition is met?

For example, I need the first value when is = 1 and partition by id

TableA

```
ID    Date       IS
 1     1/1/18    0
 1     1/2/18    1
```

My work:

```
   SELECT 
   CASE
   WHEN A.IS = 1 THEN A.DATE END)OVER (PARTITION BY A.ID ORDER BY A.DATE)                
   END FIRST_ATTEMPT_DT
   FROM TABLEA A
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `min()` instead:

```
select min(case when a.is = 1 then a.date end) over (partition by a.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use in such a way like below :

```
   SELECT 
   (CASE
   WHEN A."is" = 1 THEN 
        First_Value("Date") OVER (PARTITION BY A.ID ORDER BY A."Date")  
   ELSE
        A."Date"
   END) as FIRST_ATTEMPT_DT
   FROM TABLEA A
   WHERE "is" = 1;
```

Where *IS* and *DATE* are preserved keywords in Oracle, and so they should be quoted.

P.S. It seems you want to see the result for *First_Values* and I matched it for the case with *"is" = 1*

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7f50f/13)